# WinError 2 The system cannot find the file specified in Image process

Tags: python-3.x, ls, file-not-found

I am trying to set a path for my Image process of a data set and there I see a WinError 2. Can you please let me know where I am going wrong?

I have a basepath for my location and checking for Types in the image dataset.

```
basepath = ""
# check the types in training data
print(check_output(["ls", basepath]).decode("utf8"))
```

Error:

```
<ipython-input-23-47b705369740> in <module>
  1 basepath = ""
  2 # check the types in training data
----> 3 print(check_output(["ls", basepath]).decode("utf8"))

E:\Anaconda_File\Anaconda_App\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, 
*popenargs, **kwargs)
393 
394     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 395                **kwargs).stdout
396 
397 

E:\Anaconda_File\Anaconda_App\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, 
capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
470         kwargs['stderr'] = PIPE
471 
--> 472     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
473         try:
474             stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, 
timeout=timeout)

E:\Anaconda_File\Anaconda_App\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, 
bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, 
cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, 
restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
773                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
774                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 775                                 restore_signals
start_new_session)
776         except:
777             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

E:\Anaconda_File\Anaconda_App\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, 
args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, 
creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, 
errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
1176                                          env,
1177                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is 
not None else None,
-> 1178                                          startupinfo)
1179             finally:
1180                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of 
those pipe

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: `ls ""` says that there's no file `""` in your directory. I have no idea how is this question related to image processing and neural networks

Comment: I am in a pre-processing of Images. There is a CSV file which I have to read and link to the images in the train data set and I tried giving the path " ". Still I get the same error

Comment: Try `basepath = "./"`